# How to display posts from home page in blogs in category wise

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy, blog-page

actually i am converting html to wordpress and i have posts on home i  want to display them on blog page in category wise rightnow my blog page in working on index.php, I have made some post dynamic using custom post type and taxonomy. but cannot display them on blog page
. Need help